# Can't add react navigation in my project

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[When I am trying to add any package and import. I always got this error. can't add navigation bar. Please help I am trying this from 3 days.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7l0V.jpg)

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and correct your question.

Answer (score 0):

yarn add react-navigation

## or with npm

## npm install --save react-navigation

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html

For creating navigation

import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'

```
const AppNavigation = StackNavigator({
    Screen1: {screen: Screen1Component},
    Screen1: {screen: Screen1Component},
})
```

Use AppNavigation as main component for your app.

https://medium.com/async-la/react-navigation-stacks-tabs-and-drawers-oh-my-92edd606e4db

Comment: this is a set of instructions, but it doesn't really explain how or why the solution was recommended